Error on installing any npm package in Next App
I am using Clerk and NextJS, I have installed the latest versions of both. I have been getting this error whenever I install a new package.
npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm error
npm error While resolving: @iconify/react@5.0.2
npm error Found: react@19.0.0-rc-69d4b800-20241021
npm error node_modules/react
npm error   peer react@">=18 || >=19.0.0-beta" from @clerk/clerk-react@5.13.1
npm error   node_modules/@clerk/clerk-react
npm error     @clerk/clerk-react@"5.13.1" from @clerk/nextjs@6.0.2
npm error     node_modules/@clerk/nextjs
npm error       @clerk/nextjs@"^6.0.2" from the root project
npm error   peer react@">=18 || >=19.0.0-beta" from @clerk/nextjs@6.0.2
npm error   node_modules/@clerk/nextjs
npm error     @clerk/nextjs@"^6.0.2" from the root project
npm error   6 more (@clerk/shared, lucide-react, next, react-dom, styled-jsx, the root project)
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer react@">=16" from @iconify/react@5.0.2
npm error node_modules/@iconify/react
npm error   @iconify/react@"^5.0.2" from the root project
npm error
npm error Conflicting peer dependency: react@18.3.1
npm error node_modules/react
npm error   peer react@">=16" from @iconify/react@5.0.2
npm error   node_modules/@iconify/react
npm error     @iconify/react@"^5.0.2" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm error

I can install packages by using turnaround --legacy-peer-deps but i want to get rid of this error message.
I uninstalled and installed both nextjs and clerk but nothing helped.

check peer dependencies specified in package.json file and the dependencies of the conflicting packages your issue with the version is
@iconify/react@5.0.2 requires react@>=16.
@clerk/clerk-react@5.13.1 supports react@>=18

then do Use
npm cache clean --force
npm install

I had a similar issue on a project and fixed it by reviewing manually all packages versions, did you try to downgrade react ? Maybe it could fix your issue.
